# Angular Form Array And Angular Material Table. Error: Could not find column with id "position"

Tags: angular, formarray, angular-material-table

I'm trying to do an Angular Material Table with Form Array,
but I'm getting the error:

```
Could not find column with id "position".
```

I saw a lot of answers about the directive **matColumnDef**, but I have this at my code. [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758215/getting-the-error-could-not-find-column-with-id-id) and the name is the same with the dataSource. [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393933/error-cdk-table-could-not-find-column-with-id-angular-2-material-data-tables?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
   <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [formControlName]='arrayOfProperties[0]' > {{element.position}} </td>
              </ng-container>
```

You can see my code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyu1y4?file=src/main.ts

you can find the error at the browser console

I think it'something about the way that I am building the table here:

```
<div formArrayName="tourTable" *ngFor="let controls of tourTable.controls; let i = index;">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mannage a FormArrray with a mat-table it's not equal than another table.

The simpler way is use as dataSource: `tourTable.controls`. Yes, we can use an array to "feed" the dataSource, so we are using an array of FormGroups (that really is a formArray.controls)

As we know the elements are formGroups, so we can use this in our td

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > No. </th>

   <!--see how we say that we are using as formGroup the "element"-->
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [formGroup]="element">

        <input [formControlName]='arrayOfProperties[0]' >
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Yes it's a bit "bizarro" repeat the `[formGroup]` in each element, the another way is create a function that return the formControl at index

```
getControl(index:number,name:string)
{
   return this.tourTable.at(index).get(name) as FormControl
}
```

And use `[FormControl]`instead of `formControlName`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > No. </th>

   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let index=index" >

        <input [formControl]='getControl(index,arrayOfProperties[0])' >
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

NOTE: Don't forget use `this.table.renderRows()` when add a new element to the array

NOTE2: I'm not prety sure if was necessary in strict mode use a getter to the controls

```
  get controls(){
    return this.tourTable.controls as FormGroup[]
  }
```

And use

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="controls">
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egfzvg?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: with this code, how I can find the index from the table so I can use at the method remove?

Comment: I can t have the dataSource equal the controls because my Data is diferent, with different name of propertis, from my Reactive Form. So I need to keep both

Comment: Another Question: How can I bind some data without beeing in Input

Comment: you can get the index using `let index=index` in the td with *matCellDef: `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let index=index" [formGroup]="element">{{index}}`. This allow you call to `remove(index)` or if you has an array with the same number of elements write `{{myArray[index]}}`